# Identify a text in a file which contains path(including * asterisk) in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Input:
Text file: backup_list.txt

`/home/common/xyz_V*.txt
/home/common/hello.txt
/home/mutaq/xya_*_logs.txt
/home/mutaq/xygs.txt`

Text: `/home/mutaq/xya_Juvi_V1.01_logs.txt`

Now i want to match this text in the file.
As the file has a line `/home/mutaq/xya_*_logs.txt` which is similar to the text `/home/mutaq/xya_Juvi_V1.01_logs.txt` considering asterisk(*) as the character to represent multiple character in between.

now i want to know whether the text exists in the file or not.

Using grep, i cannot differentiate with asterisk.
one way i found that i can first iterate through the backup_list.txt
and invoke ls command for each of the line and store the same in some place then, i can directly match the text with the stored value.

But is there any better way of doing this, such that i can directory search the text withing that file ?

Answer (score 0):

A first answer could be grep `-f` option, that allow grep to take parttern to search in the file pass in parameter. You could try :

```
ls /path/to/files/ | grep -f backup_list.txt
```

But to give `backup_list.txt` content to grep as pattern, '*' have to be replace by '.*' to say any character 0 or n time and '.' have to be replace by '\.' to match '.' character and not any character.

You can make replacement with sed.

Hope this help.